# Xpath error while asserting in soapui/groovy ( pass response xml assert elements in groovy method)

Tags: groovy, soapui

I've this in script assertion

```
def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
```

value of holder is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:SOME_SEARCHResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:AA:BBB:CCC:some_WS">
         <ns0:some_ID>22222</ns0:Some_ID>
         <ns0:some_ID>33333</ns0:Some_ID>
         <ns0:Status>OK</ns0:Response>
...
...
```

below is assertions method, which is in a script lib

```
def assertions(xmlHolder, String... StringToAssert){

                StringToAssert.each{
               return xmlHolder.containsKey(StringToAssert)
               }
            }
```

I am calling assertions method like below from script assertion

```
assert true==context.Change.assertions(holder,"//ns0:Some_ID")
```

but receiving below error and I couldn't understand where the error is coming from.

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 1 on line 2 in {\n[Ljava.lang.String}: Unexpected token "[" in path expression
```

**EDIT**
Final version after @albciff comments looks like below

```
def assertions(xmlHolder,String... stringToAssert){
                  def results = stringToAssert.collect{ element ->
                  return xmlHolder.containsKey(element)
                }
                return results.every{it==true}
               //return results.contains(true)

            }
```

Comment: Variable names and parameter names are best starting with lower case letters

Comment: @tim_yates  Thanks. I'll change. Any idea about the error.

Comment: as @tim_yates says it's better to use a lower case letters to start the xml tags, however in this case I think that the problem comes from the `assertions` function.

Comment: I mean the parameter names, as in: `String... StringToAssert`

Comment: @tim_yates ops... right, but this not solve the problem isn't? maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your assertions function definition, because instead of passing each element of the array `StringToAssert` individually, you're passing the whole array. This is why you get `Unexpected token "[" in path expression` because in your example `xmlHolder.containsKey` is receiving `["//ns0:Some_ID"]` instead of `//ns0:Some_ID`, so the holder is trying to evaluate the `[` from the array.

So you've to correct your function:

```
   StringToAssert.each{
       return xmlHolder.containsKey(StringToAssert)
   }
```

To something like:

```
   StringToAssert.each{ element ->
       // now you pass the element of the array instead the whole array
       return xmlHolder.containsKey(element)
   }
```

Or use `collect` to get all `containsKey` results in a list:

```
    def results = StringToAssert.collect{ elem ->
        return xmlHolder.containsKey(elem)
    }
```

Beside there is another problems in your code. Your XPath is incorrect, in your xml `<some_ID>` starts lower case however your XPath not `"//ns0:Some_ID"` an also since in your XPath `ns0` prefix is not defined, better use `*` wildcard to match the node, so finally your XPath must be `"//*:some_ID"`.

The last is in your assert, you're comparing the `assertions` function result against `true`:

```
assert true==context.Change.assertions(holder,"//ns0:Some_ID")
```

Since your `assertions` function doesn't return nothing, by default groovy returns the last object you use, in this case the parameter `stringToAssert` so really you're doing something like:

```
assert true==["//ns0:Some_ID"]
```

This is why your assert fails. So change the return from `assertions` function.

If all the things are corrected the code could looks like:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xml = '''<ns0:SOME_SEARCHResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:AA:BBB:CCC:some_WS">
         <ns0:some_ID>22222</ns0:some_ID>
         <ns0:some_ID>33333</ns0:some_ID>
         <ns0:Status>OK</ns0:Status>
     </ns0:SOME_SEARCHResponse>'''

def holder = new XmlHolder( xml )

def assertions(xmlHolder, String... stringToAssert){
    // check if xmlHolder contains at least one
    // element defined in the xpaths arrays
    def results = stringToAssert.collect{ elem ->
        return xmlHolder.containsKey(elem)
    }

     // if at least one xpath is satisfied returns true
    return results.contains(true)
}

assert true==holder.containsKey('//*:some_ID')
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks. That error is gone now. I'll mark it as answer, though I am not seeing the desired result. I get `assert true ==context.Change.assertions(holder,"//ns0:some_Date") | | | | | | | | | com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder@f7dcdd0 (toString() threw java.lang.NullPointerException) | | | [//ns0:some_Date] ` now. Any idea?

Comment: @user1207289 there are other errors, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That worked very well. `some_id` is a typo. I'll edit. Beside that  I updated it a bit to return true, only if everything matched. I'll  include final version in above edit.

Comment: @user1207289 nice to help you `:)`